# Adblock+ can't block popup (new tab) ads

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, adblock, extension

Adblock+ can't detect and prevent popup ads. I have tried inserting some addresses to the filter but it still can't contain them.

Also there are these new types of popup ads where the new tab redirects to the original site and the original tab shows the ads. These also seem to get through.

They open something like these, which then redirect to some random ads:

```
data:text/html;base64,PGh0bWw+PGJvZHk+[RANDOM TEXT AND NUMBERS]
```

2 questions:
1- How do I block these ads using Adblock+ and is there an easy way to add new filters without learning all the formatting etc?
2- Is there a better alternative to Adblock+ that blocks these ads and is easier, more friendly to use?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try reporting these to AdBlock+'s developers! You may be able to use other adblock extensions like AdGuard or the like in order to stop them from appearing.

You can [report an issue](https://adblockplus.org/en/bugs) and they might take a look at it before the next release. In the meantime, if sites seem shady, avoid them. You should also take a look at your chrome extensions and see if another extension may be causing the exploit.

Good luck!

~ {firstName}

Comment: Is there a way to check for conflicting extensions. The only two other extensions that I think might conflict, that I have, are Ghostery and HTTPS Everywhere.